# phpsdk_deps returns fatal error on windows

Tags: php, windows

To compile PHP 7.1.X on Windows I use steps written here:

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

When I try to update dependencies with following command:

```
phpsdk_deps -u
```

I get following error:

```
D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc14\x64_71_2\php-7.1.15-src
$ phpsdk_deps -u
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught SDK\Exception: Failed to fetch supported
>   branches

This is happening for almost two weeks now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to download a pre compiled version of PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly Wouldn't it be more constructive to help solving the issue?

Comment: @Xenos If I could I would. But as I never bother compiling PHP on Windows as there are perfectly good pre-compiled versions out there I cant :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you're willing to contribute to PHP, then you must be able to build (and `make test`), so you cannot reuse already built binaries. Anyway, IMO, when you suggest these kind of by-pass-to-the-result, you should avoid the "negative-question" way of writing, and provide links to the built binaries

Answer (score 0):

You're having network trouble.

If you open up the Config.php file at this line, you'll see that the Config tries to load the URI `https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/series/`, and pick the correct txt file from there, in order to download the right dependencies. The exception you get means that this cannot be properly fetched.

The solution in my case was to use the company proxy (command line wasn't using it, so it cannot properly resolve & reach the above URL, and so the Config.php gets an empty response). How to do so might change depending on the network settings you use. In my case, I simply visited the URL above in Firefox (which is properly configured by the company), opened up the network pannel, get the IP of the website from there (which is actually the IP of the proxy Firefox was told to use by the company settings), and add the `IP hostname` entry in my host file (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\host`) so it looks like `10.1.2.3 windows.php.net`

Then I rerun the Config script, and boom, it managed to retrieve the txt files and the dependencies.

Another solution can be to retrieve all the dependencies listed in the txt file that corresponds to your setup, but it's a bit tedious...